# Learning by Making a USB data/power PCB - Will my design work?

Tags: voltage, usb, pcb-design, amperage

Ever since I watched one of GreatScott!'s videos a while ago, I have wanted to make my own PCB. I now have an excuse to build one.(A school robotics project)

I am making a PCB to connect power from a battery bank (1A 5V), and data only USB for a Raspberry Pi. There would be a power output for the L298N and data and power and data from a USB port to a USB hub. (Yes, I know that there is a thing called an externally powered USB hub)

Easy EDA:
[image: diagram]
Usage:
[image]

My main question is: Would this work? I want to make sure before I buy 10 of these and wait 2 weeks.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Why not assemble it on a protoboard and find out?

Comment: What is the functional purpose of this design? I am struggling to find any...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That schematic looks reasonable to me.

As far as the physical layout goes, what'll be most important is that the USB data lines are kept short, close together, and evenly spaced. Don't split them up, and avoid passing them through vias if at all possible. Reading the [USB Platform Design Guidelines](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/hs_usb_pdg_r1_0.pdf) is probably overkill, but is recommended anyways.

The power lines are relatively forgiving. Since you have relatively few signals, placing the ground on the entire bottom layer of the board (a "ground pour") will make it simpler to route the other signals on the top layer.